# R - Transactions object -Read transactions from HDFS

Tags: r, hadoop, transactions

I'm trying to read transactions file from HDFS. For that I'm trying with:

```
transaction.data <- hdfs.read.transactions('HDFS PATH')
```

But I'm facing with this error (I don't know how can I do this using HDFS or RHDFS):

```
Error: could not find function "hdfs.read.transactions"
```

Anyone already do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is quite simple, are you sure there isn't a typo in your function call? Have you loaded the package? Do you use R via Rstudio server? if the case are you sure you are connected to the cluster?

Comment: @SabDeM I'm running into RStudio and I already install the following packages library(arules)
library(arulesViz)

Comment: The package you mentioned do not contain any function named `hdfs.read.transactions`. Are you sure you are loading the correct packages? To which packages  that function belongs to?

Comment: Maybe the correct function is `read.transactions`...

Comment: @SabDeM with read.transactions it works fine but I need to read the file from hdfs...how can I read it not using hdfs object?

Comment: I have no idea but how I am sure about it you can't call a function that does not exist and that is exactly what you are trying to do with that code. The `.` remings of Python but even in that case you can't extract a method from an object that does not exists...

Comment: @SabDeM But the problem is because I don't know I can I refer the HDFS path to use object transactions...